# Downloading storageReference to drawable

Tags: android

I would like to load an image, from Firebase Storage, to the action bar. I tried using Glide, the same way I would, if I was loading the reference into an ImageView. This wouldn’t work, I did some digging and found a reference to Glide.with(this).load(source).into(new Task){ but I wasn’t sure how to exicute this, or if it would allow me to set the image as an action bar icon/logo. Any advice would be appreciated. I am new to android. I learned java, coding desktop applications with JavaFX. The transition has taken some adjusting, and this has truly stumped me. I felt like their was probably a simple solution, but I am such a novice, it is escaping me. I have hacked at this for a few days, with no luck. I’ll take advice in any form. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after posting this I tried something new, and it worked. Here is the code I used. I downloaded it to a file, and then created a Drawable, from the file.

StorageReference image = storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Images").child("Profile_Pic");

```
        try {
            final File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");


        image.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                String pathName = localFile.getPath();
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
                actionBar.setLogo(d);




            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Toast.makeText(HowItWorksActivity.this, "OOPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(HowItWorksActivity.this, "Realy off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }StorageReference image = storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Images").child("Profile_Pic");



        try {
            final File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");


        image.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                String pathName = localFile.getPath();
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
                actionBar.setLogo(d);




            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Toast.makeText(HowItWorksActivity.this, "OOPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(HowItWorksActivity.this, "Realy off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```